# Go Language template not found in TFS Build creation

Tags: go, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild

As per microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/go/go?view=vsts&tabs=github), while creating a new build, a Go(Preview) template should be there. But no such template found for Go. I am using Microsoft Team Foundation Server (On-Premises) 2018. Please guide me what steps I need to perform to build my Go App using TFS on-premise?

[image: No Template Found for GO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just in case you happen to stuck on same problem) I have managed to build Go App on my On-Premise TFS using Command line. Screen shot is below: (Add an empty process while setting up new build and then add command line in build step.)
[Click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrzZz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Go(preview) build template only exists in VSTS currently. You could test in VSTS by [creating a VSTS account for free](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=307137) temporarily.

---

Add screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way we can build using Command Line in build steps?

Comment: Yes, you need to have Go installed on the agent machine.

Comment: Yes I did install but I am unable to understand which "Tool" and "Arguments" to pass to command line to build Go app.

Comment: You could refer to the VSTS build process template. It needs to run `go get` and `go build` commands.